Can I re-use a covering letter for two simultaneous internal applications?
The department I work in recently created a new role, which would be one step up from my current role in terms of promotion. To re-iterate this is entirely new, and would create a level of seniority which currently does not exist at the company. I have applied for it.
By co-incidence, an opening has also come up for a role which is currently one step above mine but which, when the new role is instituted, would be two steps. I would also like to apply for this, and have been encouraged to do so. I believe all the people that are applying for the new role are similarly being encouraged to apply for this vacancy. The new role has not yet been filled, and I believe the plan is to make both appointments at the same time, so I will be submitting a second application very shortly after my first.
The skills and experience required are very similar. The only major difference is that the new role has no line management responsibilities, whereas the vacancy has.
Given that the two role are so similar, I am at a loss as to what to do with my covering letter, other than tweak it slightly to talk about line management skills and experience (which I can demonstrate). Rewriting it to talk about exactly the same things as it does currently but with different turns of phrase seems absurd. But at the same time, just submitting a slightly tweaked version of it seems lazy.
Would it be acceptable to re-submit what's largely the same letter for my second application?

The (often misunderstood) purposes of a cover letter are

Connect the requirements of the position to your resume
Explain why the role is a good fit for you
Explain why you are a good fit for the role/company

If there is a lot of overlap between two roles you could use the same cover letter.
I would make this dependent on who the audience for the cover letter is. If the interviewers or hiring managers are mostly the same people, than I think a single cover letter would be better especially if it includes a section about your pros/cons and preferences between the two roles.
If you the audience are different people, I would go with two separate ones with one talking about your "line manager" skills and the other one without. Lots of copy and pasting is fine here.


Would it be acceptable to re-submit what's largely the same letter for my second application?

Yes.
The reason is "the skills and experience required are very similar" (for these 2 positions).

You are lucky.

The skills and experience required are very similar. The only major
difference is that the new role has no line management
responsibilities, whereas the vacancy has.

In many systems you can only have one resume and one cover letter active in the job application system. I have been in the situation where I wanted different cover letters because I was applying for vastly different jobs. Because I had zero control over when they would read my documents, I had no way of trying to juggle two different cover letters.
You should try and write a common letter so that both hiring mangers will read the letter and move you on to the next step of the process.
